# How to read CPU die temperature on a mac with python without being asked for a password?

Tags: python, macos, temperature

From the code below I want to get the CPU temperature but the following error appears:

```
Error: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

I tried many things to bypass the password but nothing worked, can anyone help me please?

```
import subprocess

command = "sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i 'CPU die temperature'"

try:
    result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    if result.returncode == 0:
        # Command was successful, and the output is in result.stdout
        output = result.stdout
        print(output)
    else:
        # There was an error, and the error message is in result.stderr
        error_message = result.stderr
        print(f"Error: {error_message}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: The `powermetrics` tool needs to be run as root, there's no two ways about it. You could set up a setuid binary to wrap that, but you'd have to be careful (as always with setuid).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid being prompted for a password in the middle of the script by removing sudo from the `command` string.

If `powermetrics` needs to be elevated, what you will then get is a *permission denied* error.

If use `sudo` to launch your Python script (ie `sudo python _script name_`):

- You will be prompted for the password before the Python script starts.
- `powermetrics` will be elevated when `subprocess.run` launches it.

Comment: ... but then the Python script has root privileges, which is not a great idea.